# Windows 10 access keyboard light on laptop

Tags: c#, windows-10

I recently purchased a lenovo t420 laptop. I upgraded it with an SSD and did the update from 7 to 10. I then installed a clean image of windows 10, without all the bloatware. I would like to have access to the keyboard light without installing the Lenovo software. It isnt a backlight but is a single white LED next to the camera above the display. I see it come on for a split second when I cold boot the machine, I'm assuming this is part of the POST test or similar boot process and as such I would think there would be some way for me to connect to it.

I have tried using the new Lamp class in the windows 10 UWP API, and that doesnt work. I also tried using the device enumeration method and that doesnt show anything that looks like the LED.

Here is the code I tried so far, condensed a bit.

```
Lamp lamp = await Lamp.GetDefaultAsync();
```

this reults in lamp = null

```
string selectorString = Lamp.GetDeviceSelector();
DeviceInformationCollection devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(selectorString);
```

this also results in null

this is the device enumeration code:

```
DeviceInformationCollection devices = devices = await light.EnumerateDevices();
```

This gives me about 291 different devices in the collection, none of which seem to match. I have held back on posting here as the list is long but can if requested.

Is there any way for me to access the LED through C#, if not C# than perhaps another language?

EDIT: I just found the keyboard key, I had bad info before, its Fn + Pgup. That works so i guess I dont need to write something myself but I am still curious as to why I cant find a hook to it.

As a learning exercise I would still like to know how to access the LED.

Comment: You probably need some low level I/O drivers. There is a good chance your light/lamp is not even getting detected, let alone being recognised by the OS.

Comment: @Quirk I had suspected as much. I looked at the lenovo site and cant find a driver just for the light. Perhaps I can find one that does and extract what I need from it.

Comment: I have a feeling the light is connected to the operation of your webcam. Have you tested that fact?

Comment: @Quirk Yes, I did try that. I hoped it would be used as a flash, but it isnt. The orientation is straight down and wouldnt work very well as a flash anyway. See my edit, I found the keyboard shortcut and it worked.

Comment: I'll admit that its very strange that a dedicated lamp exists just beside your webcam. My laptop has one too, except its downright invisible until I turn my webcam on.

Comment: @Quirk it is a keyboard illumination light. Its not something I see a lot, usually the keyboard has a few RGB LED's behind it. This was a cheap laptop so I guess this was easier.

Comment: Apparently it's called the *ThinkLight*. For posterity: https://support.lenovo.com/in/en/documents/pd025331

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I think this is as close as I am going to get to an answer and I would like to put it here for any future curious minds.

**Here is a link to a page with a bunch of info on how to get at the ThinkLight from Linux and Windows.**

http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/ThinkLight

**And here is the important stuff in case the link breaks.**

Controlling the ThinkLight with the keyboard works on all systems since it relies on the BIOS exclusively. Just press Fn+PageUp to toggle its state between on and off.

Starting with the ##30 series models (T430, T530, W530, etc), the keystroke was changed to Fn+Space in order to better accommodate the new 6-row keyboard layout. On models with backlit keyboards, there are 4 states: off, dim backlit, full backlit, and full backlit w/ ThinkLight. Models without backlit keyboards only have ThinkLight on and ThinkLight off, which can be obtained by disabling the backlit keyboard in the BIOS of models with backlit keyboards installed.

**Software Control via thinkpad-acp**

Software Control via thinkpad-acpi
Support for controlling the light with ACPI is provided by thinkpad-acpi. After installing it, a simple

```
# echo 255 > /sys/class/leds/tpacpi\:\:thinklight/brightness
```

switches it on and a

```
# echo 0 > /sys/class/leds/tpacpi\:\:thinklight/brightness
```

switches it off again.

This allows one to control the light in scripts. Unfortunately, no known ThinkPad comes with a light sensor (yet). ;)

To use these controls in scripts without root permissions, you should run

```
# chmod 666 /sys/class/leds/tpacpi\:\:thinklight/brightness, which is probably best done using udev.
```

**Applications**

- led-notification: Pidgin plugin to use any LED to indicate new
  messages. I've forked led-notification to support the ThinkLight via
  thinkpad-acpi. The plugins below either weren't compatible with the
  latest pidgin or didn't compile for me. The original author of
  led-notification seems MIA. Another fork pidgin-led-notification to
  write user defined strings (added to Gentoo/Linux)
- gaim-thinklight: If you are using GAIM, the gaim-thinklight plugin
  will enable you to use the ThinkLight as an indicator for new
  messages. This depends on thinkpad-acpi.
- gaim-lighthink: gaim-lightthink is an alternative to gaim-thinklight.
  pidgin-blinklight:pidgin-blinklight is a replacement for
  gaim-lighthink intended for use with Pidgin.
- rocklight: rocklight is a xmms visualization plugin that makes the
  ThinkLight flash to the beat of your music. The package also includes
  a standalone stroboscope mode program.
- thinkblinkd:[1] Thinkblinkd is a python daemon to control the
  thinklight (and possibly other lights on your Thinkpad) it comes with
  the daemon and a control script.

  The script for theft alarm using HDAPS optionally flashes the
  ThinkLight when the alarm is armed (disabled by default, to enable
  set $use_light=1).
- kopete-thinklight:[2] This plugin for kopete will enable the usage of
  the thinklight as notifiaction for new messages. stupid little hack
  to blink the ThinkLight: [3] A little C program that may be set SUID
  so that you can use it from non-privileged programs that needs to do
  a little notification.
- thinkalert: [4] Another C program that may be set SUID to allow
  non-privileged programs to manipulate the ThinkLight. Adds some
  features over the "stupid little hack to blink the ThinkLight"
  program.
- thinklight-notification: This Evolution plugin notifies the user with
  a blinking light whenever a new message has arrived.
- ThinkBlink: blink.sh is an universal bash script making ThinkLight
  blink. It can be used with any application.

**Windows support**
Likewise, controlling the ThinkLight with the keyboard works without any additional software. The Hotkey Features software from IBM/Lenovo adds OSD icons that appear when the light is turned on/off.

**Software control via Hotkey Features**
The Hotkey Features software exposes an interface that allows (among other things) to control the ThinkLight. See Python script for Windows to control ThinkPad features for more information